# Downloading Eclipse's Source Code

Tags: java, eclipse, cvs

I'm doing a study on large Java projects and would like to view the source code for Eclipse.  I have gone to this url (http://wiki.eclipse.org/index.php/CVS_Howto) and figured that the most useful cvs repository for me to look at would be this one:

:pserver:anonymous@dev.eclipse.org:/cvsroot/eclipse (The Eclipse platform project)

However, when looking at this repository, it has so many modules! Which modules should I be trying to check out?  I don't necessarily want to build the IDE from source, however, I just want to get the core Eclipse code base to perform some analysis.  Would I just check out any modules starting with "org.eclipse..."?  Should I be checking out any of the others?

Or is there an easier way to get the source?  I read somewhere that you can get the source from the binary version of Eclipse but I am unsure where to find the source.

Comment: not sure why this question was closed as "off-topic".  seems very on-topic to me!  I voted it up.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just download the source tarball `eclipse-cvs.tgz` [from here](http://archive.eclipse.org/arch/)

EDIT: This also includes version history, so it may be larger than you need. For just a current version download [Platform-SDK.3.5.2](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/eclipse/downloads/drops/R-3.5.2-201002111343/eclipse-platform-SDK-3.5.2-win32.zip) ~ 100MB

It includes the sources in jar files e.g.

```
org.eclipse.ui.workbench_3.5.2.M20100113-0800.jar
org.eclipse.ui.workbench.source_3.5.2.M20100113-0800.jar
```

Answer (score 3):

For empirical studies, a good resource to check out is the [Qualitas Corpus](http://www.cs.auckland.ac.nz/~ewan/corpus/). It's a collection of open-source Java programs for use in empirical studies. In addition to having source code for a larger number of major projects (including Eclipse) they have multiple versions of each program, so you can track how code changes over time, if that's important. It's a respected corpus in the Software Engineering/Programming Languages research community, and so it may make your work more suitable for comparison in the future.

I'm not a part of their project, but I have used their corpus in a recent study. If you shoot them an email and tell them what your project is about, they'll give you http download access.

Answer (score 2):

I can only answer this bit:

> Or is there an easier way to get the
>   source? I read somewhere that you can
>   get the source from the binary version
>   of Eclipse but I am unsure where to
>   find the source.

In eclipse/plugins/, the jars named `*.source_*.jar` contain source.  For example, in my install:

```
org.eclipse.osgi_3.4.0.v20080605-1900.jar
org.eclipse.osgi.source_3.4.0.v20080605-1900.jar
```

The first jar contains the OSGi runtime, and the latter contains the corresponding source.