# Downloading Eclipse Source Code

Tags: java, eclipse, cvs

Before this question is blocked for duplication, I would like to mention is that this is an extension of a previous question here: [Downloading Eclipse's Source Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2890757/downloading-eclipses-source-code)

Here's what I need: I am working on a research project on evolution of open-source projects over time. I am concentrating on major releases of Eclipse (such as 3.4, 3.5, 3.6, etc.). Hence I need source code for Eclipse IDE (and IDE only) for specific versions that I have in mind (for e.g. releases with some time gap between them, etc.) (and not all major/minor versions).

The accepted answer for the above mentioned question states that I can download the whole ~7 GB file and pick and choose specific versions.
Instead, is there a way that I can download source for Eclipse IDE for specific versions?
For e.g. Apache maintains an a zip file per release for every project: http://archive.apache.org/dist/

I added the repository mentioned in the above question and as the questioner states, I too got confused by the number of different modules that I can't understand which ones to download (that correspond to IDE).

Note: I stumbled upon this page for Eclipse builds: http://archive.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/index.php. Can I get source for IDE (and only IDE) from this page for specific versions?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Eclipse SDK ships with Source bundles. These bundles contain the source code used for that version, but you can't really build them to get the IDE.  These are shipped so that developers can see / use the source while they're developing their own application.

Depending on what you're trying to do in your research project, these bundles might be enough. For example, if you want to do some analysis techniques or code metrics, you can probably just use these. You can download old SDKs from the [archive server](http://archive.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/).

If this is not enough, and you need to re-create the exact source code that was used for each release, you'll need to clone the Git repositories and checkout the tag associated with Each release. This is going to be complicated since there are about 22 different source repos for the IDE alone. Here is a link to the [list of repos](http://git.eclipse.org/c/platform/eclipse.platform.releng.maps.git/tree/org.eclipse.releng/tagging/repositories.txt).

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. So I want to download the source code for SDK. I went to the first link and went to the folder for version 4.1. Should I be downloading the source builds from this page: http://archive.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops4/R-4.1-201106201631/sourceBuilds.php#EclipseSDK

Comment: Yes, I would try those.  The source will likely be in the plugins/ directory, and they will have _source in their name. You will likely have to expand the jars and dig around a bit.  Since you're doing this as a research project, I assume you're up for the challenge :-)

Answer (score 1):

Download appropriate "Eclipse SDK" packages - they are Eclipse Platform + Java Tools + Plug-in Tools with complete sources.

Comment: Can you please provide the link where I can download the source code for SDK for specific (and not necessarily all) version?

Comment: You don't need a separate download - it's in the SDK bundle. See theirbull's answer.