# How do I download and build code of Eclipse IDE for Java?

Tags: java, eclipse

Is there any manual on this? I can't find any.
What are necessary packages and where is their repo, what is the project structure and build process?
UPD the ultimate goal I'm trying to achieve is to debug Eclipse on Windows

Comment: Well, building Eclipse from scratch is a complex process. I would take the source RPM from Fedora Project or better files from [Fedora GIT repository for Eclipse](http://pkgs.fedoraproject.org/cgit/eclipse.git/) and carefully study [the build spec](http://pkgs.fedoraproject.org/cgit/eclipse.git/tree/eclipse.spec)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check these links

- http://wiki.eclipse.org/Development_Resources
- https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse_Corner#Eclipse_Platform_Technical_Overview
- https://wiki.eclipse.org/Platform_UI/How_to_Contribute#Setting_up_your_SDK
- http://wiki.eclipse.org/Platform

There is a new tool called [oomph](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse_Oomph_Installer) Try this its easy to setup development environment. Check this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_QlSosecEUo&list=UUej18QqbZDxuYxyERPgs2Fw)

Answer (score 0):

Unable to comment so posting as answer

Please check this link should get you started

http://archive.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops/R-3.1.2-200601181600/srcIncludedBuildInstructions.html

I agree with the comment from @user3159253 . Cannot really understand the need to go through this trouble. Use RPM.

Comment: Well, because I need to debug it. And I can't use RPM as the thing I want to debug is only happening on Windows.

Comment: That is a **very** old version of Eclipse, builds have changed dramatically since then

Comment: Check the accepted answer of the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12646058/downloading-eclipse-source-code .      
Also look at the link 
http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipsePlatformDevelopment/article.htm .    
I think you can find more links related by searching for how to contribute to eclipse ide project instead of how to build eclipse from source.  Best of luck for your effort.