# import eclipse-sourcecode into eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

Is it possible to import the eclipse-sourcecode into eclipse in order to debug through it?
I have downloaded the eclipse source:
**[Downloading Eclipse's Source Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2890757/downloading-eclipses-source-code)**
imported it to eclipse but i don't know how to run it.
I thought it would be like Eclipse-Plugin development where a new eclipse-instance starts when i run the code.

I'm looking for a way to get the SVN changeset, but i didn't find some helpful Information.
So I want to analyze how the Eclipse-Team Plugin works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<del>To start Eclipse inside Eclipse you define a new "Eclipse Application" launcher and choose "Run a product" on the launcher "Main" page and select "org.eclipse.sdk.ide" in the combo box. Please clarify your question if this is not what you want.</del>

The filename you gave looks like this is the ZIP from the "Eclipse Classic" download. To import projects from this into your workspace you would first have to unzip it somewhere then use "Import->Archive" on a plugin jar file to see the classes and be able to set breakpoints on them.
But: you say you want to debug the SVN plugin. If the file you have is in fact Eclipse Classic it will contain the Eclipse source alright but not the SVN team plugin (and the source for that). The easiest way to get this is to install "Subversive SVN Team Provider Sources" from the "Help->Install New Software..." dialog. Then you can use the "Import->Archive" on the plugin jar (you wont need the SDK-ZIP for this).

(edited in response to comments)

Comment: yes, running an eclipse application is no Problem. What i want is, that i can set a breakpoint in the eclipse-sourcecode itself to debug it. In order to learn, how the Team-Plugin works. (which provids the svn-changeset  <-- i Need the changeset

Comment: You need to open the specific class and put the breakpoint where you want to debug

Comment: When you say you "imported the source into eclipse" do you mean that you put it into your Eclipse folder or do you mean you imported it into a your workspace? To be able to set a breakpoint you must import into a workspace (or create a project requiring the plugin in question, that will make the code show up in the views too).

Comment: First of all - Thanks for your answers!
This is what i did:
1.) Created a new Java Project
2.) Imported "File System" ("eclipse-platform-SDK-3.5.2-win32") to the Project which I've just created.

and now i dont know how to run/debug it. I want to set a breakpoint at a specific Point to go through the code.

Comment: yes, thx. but Debugging doesn't work at all.
Anyway, I can view the source code in a more comfortable way than with Notepad++